# Join/Sort Running Slowly

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I spent several hours crafting an SQL query that executes a `JOIN` and sorts two columns together, in a way that I haven't dealt with before.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT `m`.`id`, `m`.`primary_category_id`, `m`.`primary_category_priority`, `m`.`description`
FROM (`merchant` AS m)
LEFT JOIN `merchant_category`
    ON `merchant_category`.`merchant_id` = `m`.`id`
WHERE
    `merchant_category`.`category_id` = '2'
    OR `m`.`primary_category_id` = '2'
GROUP BY `m`.`id`
ORDER BY
    LEAST(merchant_category.priority = 0, `primary_category_priority` = 0) ASC,
    LEAST(merchant_category.priority, `primary_category_priority` ) ASC
LIMIT 10
```

It has to sort two columns together, one from the merchant_category table, and one from the merchant table, so that they're sorted together.  Each row of the `merchant` has a a "primary" category, referred to directly in the table, and zero or more "secondary" categories, stored in the `merchant_category` table.  Now it works fine, but it's very slow: usually over a minute on my production database.  I imagine the `JOIN` plus the complex sorting is causing the problem, but what can I do?

**EDIT** Here are the two table's schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `merchant` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `primary_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `primary_category_priority` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `merchant_category` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `merchant_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: can you post the schema of tables specifically `merchant` and `merchant_category`? maybe you have missed some indexes..

Comment: Do you have indexes set-up properly? How many rows in the two tables ?

Comment: @Erik `merchant` has over 20,000 I believe, and `merchant_category` has several times more.

Comment: @JohnWoo I added the table schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add foreign key constraint on the second table,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `merchant_category` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `merchant_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT mc_fk FOREIGN KEY (`merchant_id`) REFERENCES `merchant`(`id`)
)
```

Comment: @Jonah what are you trying to sort?

Comment: By a priority number that is in two different tables.  In the `merchant` table for the primary category, and in the `merchant_category` table for the secondary categories.

Comment: Okay, I added the foreign key constraint, should I expect my query to run more quickly now?

Comment: as expected, maybe. did you try to run the query again?

Comment: wow, that sped it up so much, it's basically instant now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're forcing it to run `LEAST` (twice!) for each row in order to sort it.  It can't use an index for this.

Comment: What would you recommend as an alternative?

Comment: I had to use `LEAST` to integrate the two numbers, in order to sort them together.

Comment: Two other small comments.  Shouldn't the '`merchant_category`.`category_id` = '2'' be part of the `JOIN`?  And You should have a composite index that includes the things you're selecting by and the primary key, so (primary_category_id, id).  An `EXPLAIN` would have shown a table scan on that table...

Comment: I don't know if it would be any faster, but it feels like you should use a `CASE` statement as part of the `SELECT` to determine the _priority_, and then `SORT BY` that named column.

Comment: that `WHERE` statement is just the particular category being selected in this case, it could be anything.